# Reading large text files with insuficient RAM in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to read a large text file of about 2GB and perform a series of operations on that data. Following approach

```
    tic
    fid=fopen(strcat(Name,'.dat'));
    C=textscan(fid, '%d%d%f%f%f%d');
    fclose(fid);

    %Extract cell values

    y=C{1}(1:Subsampling:end)/Subsampling;
    x=C{2}(1:Subsampling:end)/Subsampling;
   %... 
    Reflectanse=C{6}(1:Subsampling:end);
    Overlap=round(Overlap/Subsampling);
```

fails immediatly after reading C (`C=textscan(fid, '%d%d%f%f%f%d');`) with a strange peak in my memory usage: [image]
What would be the best way to import a file of this size? Is there a way to use `textscan()` to read individual parts of a text file, or are there any other functions better suited for this task?

Edit: Every column in the textscan contains an information field information for 3D-Points:

```
width  hieght X     Y      Z     Grayscale
345    453    3.422 53.435 0.234 200
346    453    3.545 52.345 0.239 200
 ... % and so on for ~40 millon points
```

Comment: Can you read and process the data one line at a time?

Comment: I can process it one line at the time, but I don't know how to use textscan() to read single rows/columns

Comment: Could you post a few lines of your text file so I have a better idea of how textscan should operate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can process each row individually then the following code will allow you to do that. I've included `start_line` and `end_line` if you want to specify a block of data.

```
headerSpec = '%s %s %s %s %s %s';
dataSpec = '%f %f %f %f %f %f';
fid=fopen('data.dat');

% Read Header
names = textscan(fid, headerSpec, 1, 'delimiter', '\t');

k = 0;
% specify a start and end line for getting a block of data
start_line = 2;
end_line = 3;

while ~feof(fid)
    k=k+1;

    if k < start_line
        continue;
    end

    if k > end_line
        break;
    end

    % get data
    C = textscan(fid, dataSpec, 1, 'delimiter', '\t');
    row = [C{1:6}]; % convert data from cell to vector

    % do what you want with the row

end

fclose(fid);
```

There is the possibility of reading in the entire file, but this will depend on the amount of memory you have available and if matlab has any restrictions in place. This can be seen by typing `memory` at the command window.